# Linking Powerpoint and Access through VBA?

Tags: ms-access, vba, powerpoint

I have a Powerpoint slide that contains textboxes. I would like to link those textboxes with a filtered view of a data table in Access.

For ex, if I had a TaskList application in Access that displayed tasks with different priorities and affectations; is there a way to open that file, select that view, and filter it according to a vba (or other) onclick button event triggered from my Powerpoint presentation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's certainly possible to get Access data from Powerpoint.

You need to make sure you have the correct references set to the`Microsoft DAO Object Library` in your VBA project.

Then, to populate your textbox in your PowerPoint presentation, you can call something like the following function, say, to return a string containing a list of Tasks matching the given TaskPriority.

```
Function GetTaskListFromAccess(taskPriority as Integer) as String
  Dim db As DAO.Database
  Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
  Dim listOfTasks as String

  Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(“C:\my_database.accdb”)

  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM TaskTable WHERE TaskPriority=" & _
                            taskPriority, dbOpenSnapshot)
  If not rs is nothing then
    If rs.RecordCount > 0 then
      With rs
        While Not .EOF
          if listOfTask = "" then 
            listOfTasks = !TaskName
           Else 
            listOfTasks = listOfTasks & vbCrLf & !TaskName
          End If
          .MoveNext
        Loop
      .Close
      End With
    End If
    Set rs = nothing
  End If
  Set db = nothing

  GetTaskListFromAccess = listOfTasks
End Function
```

Comment: Very minor quibble: whenever you're tempted in Access code to use "", instead try vbNullString. It's particularly important in a loop, since the memory for the Access constant is already defined, but "" has to be reallocated each time.